# Vagrant cannot start VirtualBox image

Tags: ruby, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

When I run `vagrant up` it goes ok, but after `Booting VM...` step it stops with error:

```
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured
properly and try again.
```

I can run my image manually with VirtualBox GUI, it loads ok and shows me `login:`.

Is there any way to find what is wrong and how to fix it?

Here are more details:

```
CPU w/o virtualization

Vagrant 1.7.4

VirtualBox 5.0.8r103449

ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]

OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro
OS Version:                6.3.9600 N/A Build 9600
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running `vagrant up --debug` to help you debug.

Comment: No, I found very hard problem. I'll describe it later.

Answer (score 1):

For vagrant to boot up your virtual machine, it will have to ssh into it. If it cannot, it won't be able to carry out the command. This only happen when you create a complete new box. In case, it works in the past (meaning you already "vagrant up" before), and decides to be a jerk this time, then you may have to check the content of vagrantfile to see any misconfig.

Comment: Thanx for an attempt. What do you mean by 'misconfig'? Could you point the examples?

Comment: So this box work before with vagrant up I assume? I can trouble shoot better if you can let me see the vagrantfile's content

Comment: Thank you for help, I found that it works only with 1 core on my PC due to https://github.com/mdaniel/virtualbox-org-svn-vbox-trunk/blob/master/src/VBox/Main/src-client/ConsoleImpl2.cpp#L1148 I'll post full answer later.